# Azure Devops - One scheduled pipeline for each branch in the repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to use one pipeline and schedule it for all branches in the repo that begins with "release"?

My scenario:
One repo - TestRepo.
Multiple release branches for TestRepo: release/alpha, release/beta, release/charlie etc.

At any given point I will have multiple release branches existing.

I have a working workaround I use right now, using the YAML file below, where I set the included branch to release/X and update that for each branch. So each branch will have its own YAML file and its own pipeline. In addition to that I also have to change the default branch in the classic editor for each pipeline to use the new release branch.

I have looked at the part concerning branches here but that didn't work for me (as in the "scheduled runs" view only took one branch into account): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#branch-considerations-for-scheduled-triggers

I appreciate any help, thank you.

```yaml
trigger: none
pr: none
pool:
  name: <REDACTED>
  demands:
  - agent.name -equals  <REDACTED>

schedules:
- cron: '0 0 * * *' # The time zone for cron schedules is UTC and Sweden is UTC+1.
  displayName: Daily nightly build for Sonarqube (code coverage %, general statistics and the dependency-check report)
  branches:
    include:
    - release/alpha # This needs to be updated for every release branch.
  always: true
  
stages:
- stage: InstallJava
  jobs:
  
    - job:
      workspace:
       clean: all
      steps:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
            script: |
              dir
              pwd
              mvn -version
              java -version
              export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.21.0.9-1.el7_9.x86_64'
          
      - task: Maven@4
        inputs:
          mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
          goals: 'dependency-check:check'
          publishJUnitResults: false
          javaHomeOption: 'path'
          jdkDirectory: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk'
          mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
          mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
          effectivePomSkip: false
          sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
        
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
            script: |
              dir
              pwd
      - task: SonarQubePrepare@5
        inputs:
          SonarQube: <REDACTED>
          scannerMode: 'Other'
          extraProperties: |
            sonar.branch.name=$(Build.SourceBranchName)
      - task: Maven@4
        inputs:
          mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
          goals: 'clean install'
          publishJUnitResults: false
          javaHomeOption: 'path'
          codeCoverageToolOption: 'JaCoCo'
          jdkDirectory: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk'
          mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
          mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
          effectivePomSkip: false
          sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
      - task: SonarQubePublish@5
        inputs:
          pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a separate pipeline for each branch, one pipeline is enough. But you need to have the **same** yaml file in each branch, and in each yaml file, change the included branch to the current branch. Refer to the sample below.

The pipeline is created based on `azure-pipelines.yml`.

The `azure-pipelines.yml` in **main** branch. The included branch is `main`.

```
schedules:
- cron: '0 */6 * * *'
  displayName: Trigger every 6 hours
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true
```

The `azure-pipelines.yml` in **release/a** branch. The included branch is `release/a`.

```
schedules:
- cron: '0 */6 * * *'
  displayName: Trigger every 6 hours
  branches:
    include:
    - release/a
  always: true
```

Go to your pipeline, click More actions -> Scheduled runs.

[image]

You can see the scheduled runs as shown below:
[image]

Comment: That didn't work for me. The two release branches have the same name for the YAML file and the same content apart from the included branch. 

I created a pipeline off the release/alpha branch but under scheduled runs I see nothing. If I change the "Default branch for manual and scheduled builds" as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-default-branch?view=azure-devops to release/alpha then I get a schedule for release/alpha but not release/beta.

Comment: Okay, so now I tried creating the pipeline off the develop branch instead, where I also have the same YAML file but with the branch develop instead. Then I get this view: https://i.imgur.com/m24SbWX.png (note, I did not create the folder or name it ".. CI"

Both of the pipelines shown there only have a schedule for the develop branch. 

It seems we're getting closer, but something must be off. Also, I would not want the develop branch to be included in the scheduled runs, only the release branches. What branch should I create the pipeline off in that case?

Comment: I got it working by deleting both release branches and creating them again. That updated the schedule to include all three branches.

My question about what branch to create the pipeline off remains though. I could create it off the release/alpha branch, but that branch won't live forever. I also don't want to create it off main/master since that branch should not be included in the schedule. Thoughts?

Comment: You can create a new pipeline based on `main` branch. In the yaml file inside the `main` branch, don't add any trigger.  Create `release/a` branch based on `main` branch. Then you will see the same yaml file in `release/a` branch. Add schedule trigger into this yaml file and add release/a as the included branch. Check the scheduled runs, you will see it only schedules for `release/a` without main branch.  The "Default branch for manual and scheduled builds" still is main and you don't need to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define multiple cron schedules in yaml like so:

```
trigger: none
pr: none

schedules:
- cron: '*/1 * * * *'
  displayName: Trigger every 1 minutes test
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true

- cron: '*/2 * * * *'
  displayName: Trigger every 2 minutes test
  branches:
    include:
    - testSchedule
  always: true
  
steps:
- script: echo Hello world!
  displayName: Say hello
```

I have tested this, and there are a few caveats to be aware of when setting it up.

- Caveat #1: You must not have configured scheduled runs via the classic user interface - this will overwrite the yaml configuration. The classic configuration menu is hidden behind multiple menus. To navigate there, select `Edit` on your pipeline, then choose the `⋮` menu and click `Triggers`. On this page is a section named `Scheduled`. If any schedules exist here, you must first delete them. You will need to `Sync schedules` from the `Schedules runs` screen to get the pipeline to read schedules from yaml if these did exist (see instructions at bottom of this message). If you prefer to manage schedules here instead of yaml, you could also do that, but I would recommend sticking to yaml.
- Caveat #2: Each branch will need a fresh commit once the pipeline has been created for it to be detected in the schedule.
- Caveat #3: Each branch should include the yaml file with the same schedule configuration in order for it to be triggered (technically it does not need to same configuration, but it should at least include itself). [Read Microsoft docs on configuring schedules for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

You can view scheduled runs by selecting the `⋮` menu and clicking `Scheduled runs`. There is also a `Sync schedules` button here to get the pipeline to use schedules from yaml instead of the classic UI.

If configured with multiple branches, it will look something like this:
[picture showing multiple branches scheduled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuYvb.png).